# How to make TraditionalForm display the same in the Manipulate output as in a notebook?

Tags: programming, manipulate

I noticed that TraditionalForm does not display as nice in the Manipulate output as in normal notebook. Is there a way to make it look the same?

Here is an example,

```
Manipulate[
TraditionalForm[-Derivative[2, 0][u][x, y]-Derivative[0, 2][u][x, y] == f[x, y]],
 {z, None}
]
```

and compare the output above to the same command, but without the Manipulate wrapper:

```
TraditionalForm[-Derivative[2, 0][u][x, y]-Derivative[0, 2][u][x, y] == f[x, y]]
```

Here is the output, side by side. (left side is the Manipulate output).

[image]

There might be an option to correct this inside Manipulate? Will keep looking. But meanwhile, any one knows why that is?

btw, I found that by Rasterizing it, it looks close to the notebook, but need to work on the resolution little:

```
Manipulate[
 Rasterize@
  TraditionalForm[-Derivative[2, 0][u][x, y] - 
     Derivative[0, 2][u][x, y] == f[x, y]],
 {z, None}
 ]
```

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is just a matter of different style (font here). This will produce identical output to what you get outside of `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[
    Style[
        TraditionalForm[-Derivative[2, 0][u][x, y] - Derivative[0, 2][u][x, y] == f[x, y]], 
        FontFamily -> "Times"
    ], 
    {z, None}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just stumbled upon this and thought it's worth adding something here: To avoid having to specify the style for every instance of `TraditionalForm` output in your `Manipulate`, you could spell out the font in the `BaseStyle` option, i.e.:

```
SetOptions[Manipulate, BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"}];

Manipulate[
 TraditionalForm[-Derivative[2, 0][u][x, y] - 
    Derivative[0, 2][u][x, y] == f[x, y]], {z, None}]
```